# How can change image position in Recently viewed product in magento 1.9.2.4?

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to call another image from that particular product but in that I'm seeing only default image.

Is it any way to display another image on recently view product

Comment: Do you mean to so more than one image to show? or you want to show different image from the same product but not the default image?

Comment: Yes, you're right. @SukumarGorai

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: @SukumarGorai I got it .
I called all the images from that particular id and apllied condition for fetch  only 2 position image path.

Comment: So it working fine now?